# JavaScript Textbox Overlay several Transparent PNGs as CSS Overlay, When Checkbox Click Show layers for all Labels checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an Interactive Building MAP. In the Header I have Labels with Checkboxes for the MAP Layers which are all TransParent PNG.  I have a base PNG which is the MAP. My checkboxes will have Cameras, Intercoms etc, with Associated Transparent PNGs that overlay the base map PNG.  When I put a check in the check box for Camera, Intercoms, etc, I want that check box to activate the Associated transparent PNG and have it OVERLAYED over top of the base PNG. So I can turn on or turn off the mapped locations of the systems, IE: If I click Cameras I see the cameras PNG Overlay. If If I click Intercoms I also see the intercoms overlay. And if I uncheck the box it deactivates the transparent PNG associated with the checkbox.

I can find many examples of using CSS to overlay images, but I cannot find some code for what I am explaining above. If I get something partially working, I will post it here as well, but I am having a hard time finding a starting point.